# How to find duplicates in the list

Tags: python, duplicates

I'm trying to find duplicates in the list acc to the pattern presented below. Let's say I have a list of lists like this and second value in each list determines if the item is a duplicate (in this case third list is a duplicate becasue it has the same value '1' in the middle as the first list):

```
a = [['1', '1', '2'], ['2', '2', '3'], ['2', '1', '2']]
```

And I would like to get two new lists, one with unique values and one with duplicates:

```
unique = []
duplicate = []
```

So in unique I should get `[['1', '1', '2'], ['2', '2', '3']]` and in duplicate `['2', '1', '2']`

What is important all values in the lists need to be preserved.

I know how to find a single duplicate values and assign them to the unique and duplicate lists...

```
for row in a:
    if row[1] not in unique:
        unique.append(row[1])
    else:
        duplicate.append(row[1])
```

... but as I said I need all values from the lists.
This is only a pattern, I'm gonna use this on a large data. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is `unique` a list of lists, but `duplicate` is a list of strings?

Comment: Create a dict with the value you're using to determine duplicates as keys, and each value as a list of lists. Basically, group your list of lists by the second value. (`{'1': [['1', ...], ...], ...}`) Then in a second step check which lists only have one entry and which have more.

Comment: @deceze I don't think that's right. They want the first item with a particular value to be in unique, and the following items to be in duplicate.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe. It's slightly confusing. But making a dict is still a useful step, even if used slightly differently then afterwards.

Comment: @deceze True, you coiuld use a dict of lists and then `unique` is the first element of each list.

Comment: You could post that as an answer, to counter the two answers that use a separate set variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're only appending `row[1]` to the result lists, not the whole `row`.

Use a separate variable to hold the values of `row[1]` that have been seen.

```
seen = set()
unique = []
duplicate = []

for row in a:
    if row[1] in seen:
        duplicate.append(row)
    else:
        seen.add(row[1])
        unique.append(row)
```